# Problem with Grub repairing (dual-boot WIndows 10/ Kali Linux)

Tags: kali-linux, grub, chroot

I am trying to repair my GRUB using [those](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?20559-How-To-Repair-Kali-Linux-Grub-With-Kali-Linux-Live-Cd-Dual-Boot-With-Windows-7) instructions:

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
umount /mnt/dev/pts
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt
```

but when I need to do the `update-grub` command, it says `command not found`, so I tried to do `apt-get update` in order to install grub (`apt-get install grub`) but I only get this output:

> Reading package lists... Done

And nothing seems to be updated.

So I started another terminal, and updated before using the `chroot` command, and it works (packets were downloaded).

Then, I installed GRUB, then tried to do the `update-grub` command after the `chroot` command, but again I get:

> command not found

I see that there is problem with the **chroot** command and the installation of new packages, but I did not find any solution yet... Any idea ?

Thank you

Roy
p.s: here is the content of the /etc/fsab file of the kali partition:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a1160db5-2803-410c-bafb-5a1202e1af6d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=7254d527-753d-47d7-9572-8064532f0cba none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

and ls /usr:

```
bin  games  include  lib  lib32  lib64  local  sbin  share  src  var
```

Comment: What is the output of `fdisk -l`?

Answer (score 0):

update-grub is a shell-skript. We can try to create it temporaly

create in chroot /usr/sbin/update-grub with following content. `#!/bin/sh
set -e
exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"`
 Make it executable as root or with sudo  `chmod +x /usr/sbin/update-grub`

Comment: Thanks, but when I execute your script, I get grub-mkconfig: not found

Comment: Hm, can you show from brocken system `cat /etc/fstab`  Is /usr on a own Partition?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but I updated my post to answer to your question

Comment: I am trying to repair GRUB without chroot, but I get an error with `grub-install --root-directory=/media/pt /dev/sda5`, I think it comes from `/etc/fstab` as you noticed

Comment: I mean /etc/fstab from brocken System not from Live-session.

Comment: Ok, just edited :)

Comment: Ok, I was abble to run the grub-install command with no error, then I rebooted my system and saw a new grub rescue, so I booted manually to my Kali linux, now I have to make it permanent

Answer (score 0):

Chroot again. This way `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/` the next will mount the virtual filesystems `for dir in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount --bind $dir /mnt/$dir; done` For internet-access `cp -a /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf` Then chroot

```
 sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

In chroot `sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda && sudo update-grub`.